# Change Fancybox 2 Loading Icon and style

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I currently have a loading screen style on my application and want to use the same for the Fancybox loading screen to ensure uniformity.

Anyone done this before?

Comment: Just replace the images?

Answer (score 0):

easy:
try set the background to gif:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#fancybox-content { 
    background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
} 
</style>
```

another approach:
you should just attach to the build-in elements and modify the ui a little bit:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful

Comment: ok, thanks for that answer.

However, I have a blue "fade" covering the entire page when it loads...

This is the style...

#cont_loading
 {
  position:      absolute;
  height:       100%;
  width:       100%;
  vertical-align:     middle; 
  z-index:      100000;background-image:    url('img/bg/blur.png'); 
 }

how could i invoke that?